# Measure zero sets to measure zero sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I would like to collect functions which preserves measure zero sets..

Let $f:A\subseteq \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f(A)$ is of measure zero if $A$ is of measure zero..

I know some examples..

- Lipschitz continuous functions
- Absolutely continuous functions

I want to make this community wiki..

Please give only one type of function in one answer..

EDIT : This is a question that asks to collect all (not highly non trivial) functions that satisfies some property.. The question that has is  linked to this question does not solve the problem as that is saying about some specific case of topological vector spaces and some hausdorff measure.. That is about some particular problem but here i want to collect all functions that satify the condition above...

Comment: This is exactly Lusin's N condition. See for instance [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393555/about-lusins-condition-n) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property).

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499101/example-of-a-function-that-has-the-luzin-n-property-and-is-not-absolutely-cont)

Comment: @Pedro : I am trying to collect all such functions.. Please write it as an answer (in your words if possible)...

Comment: @Watson : I am trying to collect all such functions.. The question that you have linked is some special case.. I am looking for collection of all functions...

Comment: [*The Encyclopedia of Mathematics*](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Luzin-N-property) shows some examples.

Comment: @Pedro :  Thanks.. That is very mych related

Comment: I believe this Question could be improved if the OP would invest the effort to understand the *general result* linked to as a duplicate, and then make adjustments to narrow the current problem.  The specification "not highly non trivial" could in particular stand some clarification.